# Getting storage item without CORS configured

Tags: firebase, cors, firebase-storage

I fetched an item from my Firebase storage bucket via this technique (generally):

```
const url = await firebase.storage().ref('my/ref').getDownloadURL();
const filename = 'filename.ext';

const a = document.getElementById('link');
a.href = url;
a.download = filename;
a.click();
```

I did it the above way prior to trying the example from the docs:

```
storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

  // This can be downloaded directly:
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(event) {
    var blob = xhr.response;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
});
```

When trying it this way, I hit the CORS error. After adding the CORS config to my bucket, it then worked as expected. However, I cannot determine why I was able to successfully fetch it via the first technique prior to configuring CORS.

I tested it again by removing the `GET` method from my CORS config and uploading the config file again via `gsutil`. I was still able to successfully obtain the file via the first technique described above.

If this is possible to do without configuring CORS, how can I prevent it to restrict access? Odds are no one will be able to figure out the required ref to build the link, anyways, because the actual ref has multiple unique IDs that will be all but impossible to figure out. This is mainly a question out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot determine why I was able to successfully fetch it via the first technique prior to configuring CORS.

Because same-origin policy doesn't apply when the Javascript can't access the *data*.  In your first example, the JS tweaks the document and the document accesses the data.  In the second example, the JS accesses the cross-origin data, and the absence of CORS prevents such access.

> If this is possible to do without configuring CORS, how can I prevent it to restrict access?

CORS isn't designed to restrict access. (Wait, what?)  CORS is designed to *permit* access that would otherwise be assumed to be something the *user* would not want -- for scripts on one page to have access to data from another origin, including, potentially, handing over use of the user's credentials to scripts on the current page when accessing the foreign site.  CORS allows site B to tell the browser that it *expects* to be contacted by scripts from site A, and therefore such access should not be unexpected or assumed unauthorized.  It has no impact on requests that don't fall under the same origin policy.

The solution -- and I apologize if I am stating the patently obvious -- is that `getDownloadUrl()` should not be able to fetch a usable URL for the object, if the object should not in fact be accessible.  You can't trust code running on the browser, so whatever credentials are in play here should not be able to be used in this way, if the object is not intended to be accessible... otherwise you have a misconfiguration that is allowing access that should not be allowed.